# Excel table all column hyperlink fields keep getting overwritten

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, excel-365

My flow uses form data to write on a table in an Excel file. I used the action "add a row into a table". Every time a new form is submitted, the column of HYPERLINK field (name of the column is "Хавсралт") on the Excel file keeps getting overwritten by the last form submitted data. This data comes from the forms attachment URL shown below the image.
[image]

The attachment link is overwritten on an entire column. All of them have the same last form submitted attachment link value.

[image]

Making this attachment link property into a hyperlink value like below
[image]

How do you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to fill formulas in Tables, hard to fix/fight it.

Suggest you create a new column (you can hide it if you like) and have flow write the link as a string (ie not `=HYPERLINK(...)`) into this new column. Then in Excel, update your `Хавсралт` column to `=HYPERLINK([@[Хавсралт txt]])`